# Loading value from DB

Tags: ajax

I have a database table called quotes.

I would like to load a random quote from the table and after 5 seconds, have it fade out and fade in a new quote derived from the DB.

Database Layout for table 'quotes'
ID | Author | Quote

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific. Right now, it's written as a general requirement. We don't have any information about the code you wrote (or even the language you used), and we know nothing about your database choice. Plus, without showing any work around what you've done, it reads like you're asking the community to create an app for you (which is really not in scope for Stack Overflow).

Comment: This question is not clear. For general, create a route in back-end which return 'Quote' record, meanwhile make a ajax call every 5 second in Front-end

Comment: @HoàngĐăng Thank you sir! That was the type of response I was looking for :)

Comment: I will add an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For general case:
     **In Back-end**:  Create a route which returns a random 'Quote' record.
     **In Front-end**: Create an ajax call to the route every 5 second.

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for :)